# Apache Ignite 2.11.0 :: Missing ignite-spring-tx-ext in maven repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-data, ignite

We are trying to upgrading from **2.9.1** to **2.11.0** and we have already using **org.apache.ignite.transactions.spring.SpringTransactionManager** which is now not available in core lib, when we checked docs https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/spring/spring-tx#maven-configuration its suggesting to use **ignite-spring-tx-ext**. But when we used that in pom.xml, its repository dose not exist in Maven repository. Can some please help us how to solve this.

Comment: Update: I can see that release of a new extension is scheduled. https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/rc165ef3659567ec1ee93502c211bec39feeb6fe9719be15ae97809a2%40%3Cdev.ignite.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Ignite 2.11 several modules have been extracted from the core repository and moved into a separate [ignite-extensions project](https://github.com/apache/ignite-extensions), including `Apache Ignite Spring Transactions` with its own release cycle.

Unfortunately, I can't see any signs of a new ignite-extensions release ([there is only 1.0.0](https://github.com/apache/ignite-extensions/releases)) meaning that only Apache Ignite core project was updated. I suppose for now you have to wait for the new ignite-extensions release or use Ignite 2.10.